# Calculating distance from polygon to nearest polyline using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, proximity

I have a village shapefile of India and a river shapefile containing major rivers and tributaries polylines of India.

How do I calculate the distance between any village and the river nearest to it using QGIS?

Comment: Have a look at `join attributes by nearest`.

Comment: did you mean the nearest distance , right?

Comment: yes I need the nearest distance of village to the river

Answer (score 2):

Since QGIS 3.8 you can use `Join Attributes by Nearest` from Processing Toolbox (settings should be self-explaining, fields with attributes and join distance are added) and since QGIS 3.16 you can also use the expression `overlay_nearest()`, e.g. `overlay_nearest('riverlayername',"attributename_you_want",limit:=1)[0]`. This will get an attribute of the nearest river. To calculate the distance via expression, use it this way: `distance($geometry,geometry(overlay_nearest('riverlayername',$currentfeature,limit:=1)[0]))`. Just change `'riverlayername'` to the name of the layer containing the rivers.

Comment: Or, as a variant: `length(shortest_line($geometry,array_first(overlay_nearest('riverlayername',$geometry))))`

Comment: It is sufficient, starting from the layer village:
`distance ($geometry, overlay_nearest ('riverlayername', $geometry) [0])`

there is no need for limit: = 1 because it is by default for the closest one;